# Pulling from repository

Tags: docker

I just created an image :

```
docker build firstimage .
```

and tagged it as sohrabp72/firstimage and then pushed it into my repo on the Docker hub:

```
docker tag firstimage sohrabp72/firstimage
```

Then I removed the tagged image and the original image from my local machine:

```
docker rmi sohrabp72/firstimage
docker rmi firstimage
```

Now when I want to pull the image from the Docker hub repository, my local Docker does not pull it:

```
C:\Users\Sohrab> docker pull sohrabp72/firstimage
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from sohrabp72/firstimage
cbdbe7a5bc2a: Already exists
9287919c3a0f: Already exists
43a47bbd54c9: Already exists
3c1bcea295c4: Already exists
53e2ab46e733: Already exists
3b08dc288a15: Already exists
e01ad7774a4c: Already exists
Digest: sha256:f16f1cfd9e777898511259e7ff512947c27b7e7bb4f4333dd27bd809bdc77995
Status: Downloaded newer image for sohrabp72/firstimage:latest
docker.io/sohrabp72/firstimage:latest
PS C:\Users\Sohrab>
```

docker logs show some lines and say already exist. and when I look at images on my local docker, that image is there:

```
C:\Users\Sohrab> docker images
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
getting-started          latest              bfc5750a86e5        11 hours ago        231MB
sohrabp72/firstimage     latest              4e197282638a        22 hours ago        179MB
node                     12-alpine           d8b74300d554        7 days ago          89.6MB
docker/getting-started   latest              1f32459ef038        3 months ago        26.8MB
```

Is there something like a cache for images we've pushed to Docker hub?

Comment: If your dockerfile starts from another image maybe the layer that already exists belong to this image.

Comment: Docker caches the layers in an image when it's built. When you run `docker rmi firstimage` all the cached layers remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When docker prepares an image, it does step by step and each step creates an intermediate step with an ID. Docker by default removes the intermediate image and the last step provides a final image with an ID.

When you ran build command it actually created a final image with an ID and tagged the final image ID with your name 'firstimage'

When you tag second name, it added additional tag 'sohrabp72/firstimage'

When you ran docker rmi command on both tags, it removed tags only while image created still is there.

You can run

docker images -a

which will list image with <<"none">> in repository and name but final image created will be there with ID

you can

docker image prune -a

to clear all image and try docker pull command